# Ошибка при создании библиотеки boost c++ для python: невозможно найти файл, где не указана версия питона

Tags: c++, python, boost

Ошибка: не удается открыть файл "boost_pythonPY_MAJOR_VERSIONPY_MINOR_VERSION-vc141-mt-gd-x32-1_67.lib".
Во включённом stage/lib есть boost_python36-vc141-mt-gd-x32-1_67.lib. Как исправить?

Visual Studio

Comment: Нельзя просто взять и библиотеку питона к c++ прицепить

Comment: @K2Re8 а непросто как-нибудь можно? Расскажите, пожалуйста )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
108 - #define BOOST_LIB_NAME boost_python##PY_MAJOR_VERSION##PY_MINOR_VERSION
+ #define _BOOST_PYTHON_CONCAT(N, M, m) N ## M ## m
+ #define BOOST_PYTHON_CONCAT(N, M, m) _BOOST_PYTHON_CONCAT(N, M, m)
+ #define BOOST_LIB_NAME BOOST_PYTHON_CONCAT(boost_python, PY_MAJOR_VERSION, PY_MINOR_VERSION)

123 + #undef BOOST_PYTHON_CONCAT
+ #undef _BOOST_PYTHON_CONCAT
```

Нашёл здесь: github.com/boostorg/python/commit/24313709a78c694af4ae29116cd06ea86585aa95